# How to do the Time Date UTC to Local and viceversa using MongoDB and Mongoose/Express?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, express, mongoose

I want to compare the dates as per my local Timezone ***(Asia/Kolkata GMT+5.30)***.

```
var today = moment().toDate();
var tomorrow = moment().add(1,'days').toDate();
```

**Moment** : Using MomentJS (Not sure if it is applicable here)

```
Deal.find({date:{$gte: today, $lt: tomorrow}},function(err, result){
        if(err) return console.log("Error" + err);
    //Code goes here.
});
```

The ***date*** in the

> Deal.find({**date**:{$gte: **today**, $lt: **tomorrow**}},function(err, result){

is what is in GMT, while today and tomorrow are in my **LOCAL Timezone** as mentioned above.

How do I go about this? My scope is limited to my local Timezone and am not bothered about whether is it ***UTC or GMT***.

I am using a standard ***Express4, MongoDB, Mongoose ODM*** stack.

Is there any way that we could pre-process and modify the ***date*** variable to local Timezone before passing to the **Deal.find** mongoose query?

Comment: what about [`date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: It will convert to a String Object, that Mongoose Query deals with Date Object, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, I think it accepts both, another approach will be use [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) and query using that offset amount

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid Robo Mongo Setup Issue.

In the Robo Mongo Window,

> 1. Go To Options.
> 2. Select Display Dates IN.
> 3. Choose Local Time Zone.

You are sortedd then!

Cheers and Thanks!